# Can I prevent custom React subclassed components from expanding to className in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, ide, jsx, emmet

In any `.jsx` file in VSCode expanding (via emmet) any tag with dot notation will assume any characters after the dot are the class name:

`Site.Wrapper -> <Site className="Wrapper" />`

Is there any way to prevent this behavior, and have the tag expanded literally?

`Site.Wrapper -> <Site.Wrapper />`

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your user/workspace settings file:
`"emmet.excludeLanguages": ["javascript", "javascriptreact"]`

Comment: Won't this just prevent Emmet from working altogether though, or do you still get the statement wrapped in angled brackets?

Comment: Unfortunately, it disables emmet completely for js/jsx files. Other features provided by tsserver (autocompletion, go to definition etc.) will continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What I'm looking for probably isn't possible, it would be asking a lot for a parser to make such a distinction. Maybe if there was some kind of pattern matching the user could add to Emmet, e.g. whenever the first letter is a capital, maybe it could work on that premise.